# How come my AngularJS website loads 5 seconds in FF and under 1 second in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

I'm in the middle of optimizing my website, but I can't find solutions on how to make the site load faster in Firefox. It loads fine in IE and Chrome, have a look for yourself:
http://vivule.ee/0

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1) use a bundling and minification tool for your js/css.

2) don't include min.map.js files in production

3) the slow load time is not related to angular. you are loading ~110 pictures on initial page load, if these are not cached on the browser it is going to take time. my guess is chrome is caching more agressively and thats why you are seeing worse load time on firefox.